# Some times CSS not Applying

Tags: css

I was applied Custom css for footer. Sometimes i going to update the post/ or page. Footer css does not applying. footer style comes back normal / good when i flush the cache, what is the reason sometimes css not applying in footer? and I am Using wordpress4.3

Comment: How are you "applying" it and when?

Comment: Before Couple of months

Comment: Ha! No, I meant post your code. Where and when in WP's initialization process.

Answer (score 1):

I would just comment on your question but since low reputation, i have to post this as an answer.

So, with that out of the way, i have had these problems before, and what i would usually do is open the page up in incognito mode in chrome or Firefox, and make sure to clear the cache in those browsers as well. Then try viewing your page, or view that page in a browser that hasn't seen that website before.

Comment: Now i findout the issues comes from cache ...

Comment: If it has solved you problem, please mark this answer as answered.

Comment: I deleted the cache files. and cache files newly generated. some times. still the issues coming, how can i clear.?